# How to add a click\hit event for LineSeries in amcharts 4?

Tags: angular, amcharts

I want to know how to get the X\Y item details of a clicked line item in amcharts 4.

I have the code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-3qpqlq

```
series2.segments.template.events.on("hit", (ev) => {
alert('line clicked');//this gets triggered
//but how to i get the line item details here, like X axis and Y axis 
//value of the clicked point of the line?

}, this);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LineSeries data items aren't as straightforward to get from the `hit` event as columns are. You have to look at the event's `target.dataItem.component.tooltipDataItem.dataContext` object to get at the clicked bullet's information:

```
series2.segments.template.interactionsEnabled = true;
series2.segments.template.events.on(
  "hit",
  ev => {
    var item = ev.target.dataItem.component.tooltipDataItem.dataContext;
    alert("line clicked on: " + item.country + ": " + item.marketing);
  },
  this
);
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6ba679482919859377e242a774aa234a?editors=0010)

Comment: Thank you. Really had hard time finding that property :)

Comment: Really its very hard to find this solution in official doc. Thanks a lot @xorspark.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without bullets too. Just add Cursor to the chart, listen to "hit" event and series.tooltipDataItem is the one cursor is currently hovering.

```
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.events.on("hit", function(){
  console.log(series.tooltipDataItem);
})
```

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/de5de2f65752517c07afb4ffe7e110ef

Answer (score 2):

Maybe things have improved since because you can now access this via

```
bullet.events.on('over', (ev: any) => {
                    const val = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.value;
                    this.dosomethingwith(val)
                }, this);
```